# Python workout unit cost based on range

Tags: python, django

I want to work work out unit cost based on the units passed. So for example

```
0-499 = unit cost of 0.049   
500-999 = unit cost of 0.050 
999+ = unit cost of 0.060
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
unitCost = 0.049
        if self.units <= 499: 
            unitCost = 0.049
        elif self.units >= 500:
            unitCost = 0.050
        elif self.units >= 999:
             unitCost = 0.060
        else:
             unitCost = 0.049
```

First of all this does not work if I have 1000 units it matches the wrong unit cost. Second, I'm not sure this is the good way. Does Python has a between function?

I.e.

```
if x between(0-499):
```

Comment: It does not appear to do what I need it to do see example.

Comment: That is not an accurate description of your problem.

Comment: sorry, updated description

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if number is within more or less range in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502307/checking-if-number-is-within-more-or-less-range-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your if-statmement. You need to do something like `units >= 500 and units <= 999`, which basically checks if the value is between 500 and 999.

```
unitCost = 0.049

if units <= 499:
    unitCost = 0.049
elif units >= 500 and units <= 999:
    unitCost = 0.050
elif units > 999:
     unitCost = 0.060

print unitCost
```

Comment: good point on the Decimal I will use. but this still does not work with my example.

Comment: I was completely off on the decimal. I haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: using Decimal for monetary values isn't a bad idea, although I doubt it will matter in this case; you'll need to round to the nearest cent for the total anyway.

Comment: why, the decimal makes sense to me tho? could you explain?

Comment: @User7 Float has more than enough precision to handle these values.

Comment: @Wooble Yea, exactly. My mind wandered a bit off track there.

Comment: My IDE does not like it lol: it states "This inspection highlights chained comparisons that can be simplified." I wonder what it wants. Never mind this works

Comment: I am glad it worked out, and while float is enough, you are free to use decimal as well. :)

Comment: cool thanks. Just to justified why I accepted this answer. Both you and @Wooble answers seemed to work perfect, if I could have accepted both I would have. However, I did learn a lot more from this answer.

Comment: @User7: your IDE is trying to tell you my version is simpler :) (or maybe it doesn't like the last `elif` which has a condition that mathematically can't possibly be false which should probably be a bare `else:`)

Comment: @User7 Your IDE is in fact telling you to use `500 <= self.units <= 999` instead of `units >= 500 and units <= 999`, which looks like C, not Python. There will still remain the problem concerning the last `elif`, as pointed out by @Wooble (for instance, it goes against DRY).

Answer (score 4):

`elif` is only evaluated if the previous `if` is False; your third condition can never be reached.

Reverse it:

```
if self.units >= 999:
    unitCost = 0.060
elif self.units >= 500:
    unitCost = 0.050
else:
    unitCost = 0.049
```

Comment: is this the best way tho, is there a between function?

Comment: @Wooble That is between 3 and 130 times slower (it's using a O(n) algorithm instead of constant time one...). And only works if `self.units` is an integer so it will fail whenever half units are sold.

Comment: Removed, as it's ugly anyway, although I was under the impression xrange had a constant time `__contains__`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by typecasting the `self.units` to an `int` if it has a `float` value and executing the following snippet.

```
if int(self.units) in range(0, 500):
    unitCost = 0.049
elif int(self.units) in range(500, 1000):
    unitCost = 0.050
else:
    unitCost = 0.060
```

Comment: Using `in range(...)` is very slow, since the value you're looking for has to be compared to every value in the range until you reach the right one. So it is much better to use a simple comparison

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for the information. I'll be sure to avoid these in my future codes. :)