# Checking if number is within more or less range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python as part of an exercise I'm making a simple number guessing game. I've gotten the basics covered, but I'm trying to implement a manner which tells the user if their guess is close or far from the right number. I can't guess within a range because the number to be guessed is randomly selected each time. My exercise tells me to look into abs(), but that doesn't bring me much sense. It also mentions something about within(), which also doesn't do much for me. Just need a push in the right direction if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know, `within` is not a built-in.  I've never heard of it and I've used Python for ages.

Comment: Wouldn't `abs(number-guess) < rangeValue` tell you if it was within your range?

Comment: do it pythonic way: `a < x < b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to come up with values that mean close or far.
It might look something like this:

```
diff = abs(guess - random_number)
if diff >= 50:
    print("Really cold!")
elif diff >= 40:
    print("Cold.")
...
elif diff >= 5:
    print("Getting really hot!")
```

You could have a function return a number which represents how hot or cold it is (0 through 10 for example), then have a dict that looks like this:

```
hot_str = {
    0: "You guessed it!",
    1: "Extremely hot!",
    10: "Frozen cold!",
    }

print(hot_str[heat(diff)])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, great way of explaining it and I think I've got it working now. Great help, thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [operator chaining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) and test against both extremes of your range:

```
if lower <= number <= upper:
```

This test matches if `number` is in the range `[lower, upper]` (both ends inclusive).

If you wanted to see how close a value is to something else, you could use `abs(target - guess)`:

```
distance = abs(target - guess)
if 10 <= distance <= 20:
    print('You are getting closer now!')
```

A whole series of such tests are going to be tedious; you can print messages based on how close they are with a sequence of tests:

```
messages = (
    (100, 'Way, way off!'),
    (80, 'So cold, are you not freezing?'),
    (60, 'Is there a light on the horizon?'),
    (40, 'Where there is warmth, there is hope!'),
    (30, 'You are getting warmer now..'),
    (20, 'Is it just me, or is it getting hot in here?'),
    (10, 'You are about to burn yourself!'),
    (0, 'Fire, ta-cha-ta, burning desire, ta-cha-ta!')
)

distance = abs(target - guess)
if distance == 0:
    print("You guessed it right!")
else:
    for target, message in messages:
        if distance > target:
            print(message)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define close and far. For now I assume let `d` be parameter and if abs(guess-right_num) is less than `d` then it is close otherwise it is far

so the code can be:

```
if abs(guess-right_num) < d:
      print("close")
else:
      print("far")
```

Comment: It's python, you can write `a < n < b`. BTW, I think JSJ needs something else: "guess is close or far from the right number"

Comment: yep got that and changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a range to directly compare *your* number and the randomly generated number, but you can use a range to directly compare their *differences*.

`abs()` can be used to return the positive version of a number whether it is positive or negative.

```
abs(10)
10
abs(-10)
10
```

You can use this to ensure your random number is always *positive*.

You must be misreading about `within()`; This is either something accessible only to you and your class, or you misread what it meant, because `within()` is not a build-in function.

Now, on solving your problem. This takes a bit of math and logic.

You can't work within a range because the number is randomly generated. But you can always get a percentage of them and work based on *that*.

As an example, consider this number line, where the random number is 10 (denoted by `|`).

```
[(0)---------|---------(20)]
```

You will always be able to divide the number you guess by the random number and get a number that will range from (in this case) `(0/10)` and `(10/20)`. In all cases, when `number_guessed == number_generated`, the number calculated in the division operation will be equal to `1`.

I leave you to figure out the implementation of this, but the basic concept is that you can figure out how close you are to the number based on how far away you are from the number `1`.

It's not perfect either, but it's an interested and clever way that might get a professor's notice, if you do it right.